# Np.savetext align header with columns

Tags: python, numpy, save

I am trying to save a datafile with large numbers and include a header. I am stuck with aligning the header with the respective column. An example code:

```
import numpy as np
import os

Output = np.empty((0,3), int)

for i in range(30):
    Values = 10e6 * np.random.random((1,3))
    Output = np.vstack((Output, Values))

header = 'A\tB\tC'
np.savetxt('Output.txt', Output, delimiter='\t', newline=os.linesep,
            header=header, comments='')
```

My output is:

[image]

However what I want is 'A', 'B' and 'C' to be aligned with the columns, i.e:

[image]

How can I achieve this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have to create a header string with the right spacing.  The default `fmt` is `%10.5f`.  So your `header` has to take that into account.  Remember `\t` just spaces to the next tab (8 spaces); it's relative, not absolute.

Answer (score 1):

The formatting of your header has to match the formatting of the columns

For example, with a 3 columns and a `%10.5f` format, the perline format is:

```
In [185]: fmt = '\t'.join(['%10.5f']*3)
In [186]: fmt
Out[186]: '%10.5f\t%10.5f\t%10.5f'
```

So a numeric line will be written as:

```
In [187]: fmt%tuple(np.random.random(3))
Out[187]: '   0.83330\t   0.90960\t   0.07613'
```

The corresponding `header` would be:

```
In [188]: '%10s\t%10s\t%10s'%('A','B','C')
Out[188]: '         A\t         B\t         C'

In [189]: header = '%10s\t%10s\t%10s'%('A','B','C')
In [193]: np.savetxt('test.txt', np.random.random((2,3)),  delimiter='\t', heade
     ...: r=header, fmt='%10.5f') 
In [194]: cat test.txt
#          A             B           C
   0.55919     0.55277     0.47236
   0.93945     0.50398     0.56320
```

The default `fmt` is given in the signature line

> > np.savetxt(fname, X, fmt='%.18e', delimiter=' ', newline='\n', header='', footer='', comments='# ')

That's harder to match since it only specifies the number of decimal pts, not the total width.

Comment: @STJ, have you found anything that doesn't need to be hard coded?